How to select the subset which can represent the whole dataset
I have a time series of data for the whole year, which I need to run the analysis on Python. However, it takes a long time to run the model. I want to select a subset of data that can represent the full data (like 30 days instead of 365 days). My data have 8760 rows (hourly) and 4899 columns.
What is the best method to select the subset of data?

IMO, your computation issues are arising from the number of columns, and not the number of rows (i.e. the amount of time periods). What do the columns represent in your data?

The columns represent the number of loads (my data is the time series of loads on the power grid).
